# Перегрузка операции ">>" в с++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Как можно реализовать перегрузку операции `>>` так, чтоб выражение `a>>b>>c` (`a`,`b`,`c` - *объекты одного класса*) работало следующим образом:

> В объект **c** заносится значение объекта **b**, а в объект **b** - значение объекта
>   **a**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция при перегрузке должна возвращать старое значение правого операнда. Тогда результатом

```
a >> b
```

будет занесение в `b` значения `a`, а результат - старое значение `b` - будет занесено в `c`.

[Что-то вроде](https://ideone.com/Ca5S7p)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class I
{
    int i;
public:
    I(int i = 0):i(i){}
    operator int() const { return i; }
};

I operator >> (const I& a, I& b)
{
    I c = b;
    b = a;
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    I a(3), b(4), c(5);
    a >> b >> c;
    cout << a << "  " << b << "  " << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Могли бы вы пояснить для чего нужна строка "operator int() const { return i; }"?

Comment: Чтоб не писать оператор вывода - так при выводе `cout << a` будет автоматическое приведение к `int`.